# how to show the derivative of the polynomial is bounded by itself in certain space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials

How to prove that for every positive integer $d$, there exists $C(d)>0$, such that: For every polynomial with degree $\leq d$, we have $\max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}|p'(x)|\leq C(d)\max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}|p(x)|$. I don't understand the hint, which says that using the compactness of a subset in an appropriate finite dimensional space. I understand that we could view polynomial with degree $\leq d$ as vector space whose basis is $1,x,....x^{d}$, but I don't understand how can we get a compact subset since the coefficient is not bounded. Even if we define the vector space with supreme metric, it is still not bounded.

Comment: The map $T:(\mathbb{C}_d[x], \Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty)\to (\mathbb{C}_d[x], \Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty):p\mapsto p'$ is continuous as any linear operator between finite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you should apply is : **every linear map on a finite-dimensional normed vector space is bounded** (equivalently continuous), 
Let $D$ be the linear map here of the derivation and $R_d$ be the $d+1$-dimensional vector space of real polynomials, and the norm is the max value over $[0,1]$:
$$\|p\|=\sup_{[0,1]}|p(x)|$$
now what you want to prove is 
$$
\|D\|=\sup_{\|p\|\leq 1}\|D(p)\|=\sup_{p\in R_d}\frac{\|D(p)\|}{\|p\|}<\infty
$$

which means that $D$ is bouded (or continuous) and this follows from the quate on bold!

Comment: could you elaborate more on the part that why it is equivalent to what I want to prove？ Since I did not see the connection....

Comment: some says it suffices to show $\|D\|=\sup_{\|p\|\leq 1}\|Dp\|\leq\infty
$. Where $\|p\|$ denotes the unit ball.

Comment: Sorry maybe it is a trivial question, but in the second last line, why does the second equality hold? Why does $\sup_{\|p\|\leq 1}\|D(p)\|=\sup_{p\in R_d}\frac{\|D(p)\|}{\|p\|}$

Comment: Given a polynomial $p$ we have $ \frac{\|D(p)\|}{\|p\|}=\left \|D(\frac{p}{\|p\|})\right \| \leq \sup_{\|p\|\leq 1}\|D(p)\|$ , because $q=\frac{p}{\|p\|}$ verifies $\|q\|\leq 1$, and the other inequality is trivial

Comment: Oh right! Since $\|p\|$ here is a constant we can put it into the linear map! Thanks.